# Using Rules on React-Hook-Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

## Overview

I am using [React-Hook-Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) to manage validation on my input fields. I am leveraging [react bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) so I have to make use of the [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) component provided with this library.

Documentation is not clear about how to use rules; just that its that same as [register](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register#options). I am able to get one validation rule working (required). For dropdowns, I always have at least one value selected ("select"), so required does not work, instead I am trying to use regex to see if the selection is this or not.

I have tried many ways to get this work but unfortunately I can't figure this out.

## Question

Does any have experience in using React-Hook-Form with Controlled components, specifically dropdowns and regex? I am looking for the syntax on how what they define in register within the rules of the controller component. Only required seems to work

## Here is what works (notice the rules prop)

```
<TextInputField
            label="Operation Info"
            name="operation_info"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: "Operation is required" }}
            error={errors?.name}
          />
```

## This does not work (notice the rules prop)

I am trying this on another custom component except it a dropdown.

```
<Dropdown
            label="Ratings"
            name="ratings"
            control={control}
            rules={{ pattern: /^(?!select$).*/ }}
            options={ratings}
            optionsKey={"rating"}
            error={errors?.indicator}
          />
```

I tried a copy paste of their actual pattern rule but this also does not work. I am able to hook into all errors in my forms but anything using pattern does not register as an error.

This second one does not work. I spread these props on the actual react-bootstrap components in another file. They are all the same, so the fact the text-input works, means the dropdown should work as well but it does not. Only difference I see it the rules I am applying; I must be doing it wrong but there is no documentation.

Here is a sample of the dropdown component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";

export const Dropdown = (props) => {
  const { error, name, control, label, rules, options, optionsKey } = props;
  return (
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        rules={rules}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <Form.Control
            {...field}
            as="select"
            className={error ? `is-invalid` : null}
          >
            <option selected disabled className="text-muted" value="select">
              select
            </option>
            {options?.length > 0
              ? options.map((option, index) => {
                  return (
                    <option value={option[optionsKey]} key={index}>
                      {option[optionsKey]}
                    </option>
                  );
                })
              : null}
          </Form.Control>
        )}
      />
      <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
        {error?.message}
      </Form.Control.Feedback>
    </Form.Group>
  );
};
export default Dropdown;
```

here is the link to the controller documentation
https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller

Answer (score 1):

I did a minimized test setup and if I understood your question to me it looks like the problem is just with your regex. Try

```
rules={{ required: "req", pattern: /^(?!select)/ }}
```

[Click here for test sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/controller-rules-forked-37bfc6?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1114) and iIn case the sandbox goes away:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form"

const Dropdown = ({ name, control, rules, options }) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      rules={rules}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <select {...field} rules={rules}>
          <option value="select">select</option>
          <option value=""></option>
          {options.map(x => <option key={x} value={x}>{x}</option>)}
        </select>
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control, formState: {errors} } = useForm()
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log("Submit:", data)

  console.log("Errors:", errors?.ratings)

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Dropdown
        name="ratings"
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: "Requir", pattern: /^(?!select)/ }}
        options={["potato", "tomato", "select", "greg"]}
      />
      <input type="submit" />
      {errors && errors.ratings && <p>
        Error: {errors.ratings.type} {errors.ratings.message}</p>
      }
    </form>
  )
}
```